# Selected tab not being passed through to fragment in tablayout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

In a simple tabLayout view viewPager setup I am unable to correctly pass through the selected tab to the fragment within it. As tabs are selected left to right (i.e tab 1 -> tab x) the tab is correctly interpreted, but as they are selected right to left, 0 is returned.

Here is the important code:

**Activity including tabLayout:**

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new OwnPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), NavDrawer.this));

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

**PagerAdapter:**

```
public class OwnPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private int TAB_COUNT = 7;
private String tabTitles[] = new String[] {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
private Context context;

public OwnPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return OwnTimetableFragment.newInstance(position - 1);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return TAB_COUNT;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabTitles[position];
}
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
public class OwnTimetableFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String ARG_DAY = "ARG_DAY";

private int mDay;

public static OwnTimetableFragment newInstance(int day) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_DAY, day);
    OwnTimetableFragment fragment = new OwnTimetableFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDay = getArguments().getInt(ARG_DAY);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View tabView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_own_timetable, container, false);
Log.e("mDay", mDay + "");
    return tabView;
}
```

The log method call in the onCreateView of the fragment will correctly return numbers 0->6 as the tabs are swiped through left to right, but as soon as a tab left of the current tab is selected, it will return 0, which will become the new origin (i.e one tab right will become 1)

Seems as though there is something going on with fragments coming in and out of focus that might be causing this?

Comment: where are you passing as bundle `ARG_DAY` ? Your problem is you are not receiving the `ARG_DAY` in the fragment ryt?

Comment: ARG_DAY is passed in through the newInstance function - since you can't have arguments in a fragment's onCreate. It's passed through to the fragment sometimes is more the problem than not receiving it at all

Comment: so whats your issue ?

Comment: That value that the fragment ends up with is only sometimes correct - if I return to a tab that has been previously opened, the number is incorrect

Comment: post your `newInstance(int pos)` method

Comment: It's there, first method down in the lower code snippet

Comment: app starts, then you click a tab..and the value is incorrect ryt ?

Comment: If a tab to the right of the currently selected tab is selected, the position will increment by one (correct behaviour). If a tab to the left is selected, the position will return 0, no matter which tab it is

Comment: Do you happen to have a `setCurrentItem(0)` somewhere by any chance?

Comment: No setCurrentItem at all

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are passing **pos - 1** in your new instance, because of which, your first tab will display log as -1. If you want correct value, only pass **pos** in newInstance.
Other than that, make sure you are not passing any setOffscreenPageLimit in viewPager. Everthing else in your code seems to be okay.
Let me know your exact issue if you are still facing it.

Comment: The pos - 1 is leftover from another attempt at solving the issue and isn't related to the problem as such.  If a tab to the right of the currently selected tab is selected, the position will increment by one (correct behaviour). If a tab to the left is selected, the position will return 0, no matter which tab it is

Comment: Your code is working correctly in my device for this matter. Try using any other device.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue still persists across a physical device (gs8) and emulator

Comment: Have you tried putting a log in **getItem()** method in adapter..?? If you get correct value over there, and wrong value in fragment, then you might wanna try removing the newInstance and load fragments manually.

Comment: Good idea, the value is incorrect in the getItem() method, so nothing is wrong with the fragment. Is there a different inherited method I need to override to pass the correct value?

Comment: Its really confusing why your getItem method returns wrong value. Try using *viewPager.setOffScreenPageLimit(0)* in your activity, in case if we are seeing at a caching issue. If it doenst work, will try something else.

Comment: With the offscreenpagelimit, the problem isn't resolved. However, with a log in getItem(), a result is only logged the first time a tab is open

Comment: Remove the offScreenPageLimit. Try implementing FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: No difference with the Stage adapter